# Get every ms, sec with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function format(n) { return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n); }

var hour,min,sec,ms;
function timer() {
    if ((millisecond += 1) == 100) {
        millisecond = 0;
        second++;
    }
    if (second == 60) {
        second = 0;
        minute++;
    }
    if (minute == 60) {
        minute = 0;
        hour++;
    }
    hour = format(hour);
    min = format(minute);
    sec = format(second);
    ms = format(millisecond);
}
```

I'm using this piece of code to generate timestamps. Check how is the output:

```
00:00:00.01
00:00:00.02
...
00:00:10.10
00:00:10.11
00:00:10.12
...
00:02:05:01
00:02:05:02
...
```

It works perfectly! But, I'm using **setTimeout** and this is very innacurate sometimes. So, my idea is start working with **Date.Now()**, but when I use it, I got something like this as response:

```
00:00:00.02
00:00:00.05
00:00:00.07
...
00:00:07.17
00:00:00.21
00:00:00.23
...
```

It works, but I'm unable to catch every millisecond and second, and this won't fit my need! So, what should I do? Here is the code:

```
var offset = 0,
paused = true;

render();
  
function startStopwatch(evt) {
    if (paused) {
        paused = false;
        offset -= Date.now();
        render();
    }
}

function stopStopwatch(evt) {
    if (!paused) {
        paused = true;
        offset += Date.now();
    }
}

function resetStopwatch(evt) {
    if (paused) {
        offset = 0;
        render();
    } else {
        offset = -Date.now();
    }
}

function format(value, scale, modulo, padding) {
    value = Math.floor(value / scale) % modulo;
    return value.toString().padStart(padding, 0);
}


var min, sec, ms;
function render() {
    var value = paused ? offset : Date.now() + offset;

    ms = format(value, 1, 1000, 3);
    sec = format(value, 1000, 60, 2);
    min = format(value, 60000, 60, 2);
  
    if(!paused) {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why you absolutely need a list of following numbers without skipping any, but in this case, why not simply increment whole numbers? Why not just simply start with "1", then "2", then "3" etc all the way up to "99999999"?

Comment: I'm working with timers, 00:00:00.00, not with just integers

Comment: Well, just add punctuation. It's not hard to generate "00:00:00.01" then "00:00:00.02" then "00:00:00.03".

Comment: Will be inaccurate as setTimeout

Comment: Interval timers have a 4ms minimum along with other thread restrictions so you won't be able to accomplish the precision you seek